# How to handle the exception in below scenario

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

```
package com.pack.DbOPs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.pack.spliter.DbPojo;

 /**
 * @author amriteshk
 * @project TestDHProcess
 * @created 12-Sep-2018 5:42:54 pm 
 * @classname com.pack.DbOPs.TestSpringJdbc.java
 */
public class TestSpringJdbc {

    @Autowired
    private static TestDbDaoImpl testDbDaoImpl;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        DbPojo pojo=new DbPojo();
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml"); 
        try {
            pojo.setCardRdrHealth("xxx");
            pojo.setDespHealth("yyy");
            pojo.setPrinterHealth("ooo");
            pojo.setTerminalId("999");
            pojo.setVaultHealth("hjy");
            testDbDaoImpl  =(TestDbDaoImpl) ctx.getBean("edao");
            int status=testDbDaoImpl.SaveDeviceHelth(pojo);
            System.out.println(status);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            pojo.setCardRdrHealth("xxx");
            pojo.setDespHealth("yyy");
            pojo.setPrinterHealth("ooo");
            pojo.setVaultHealth("hjy");
            pojo.setTerminalId("8989");
            testDbDaoImpl  =(TestDbDaoImpl) ctx.getBean("edao");
            int status=testDbDaoImpl.SaveDeviceHelth(pojo);
            System.out.println(status);
        }
    }
}
```

In this scenario the Terminal Id is primary key,The Terminal Id is already present with "999" in the table i want to run the query with same Terminal Id value,So that it will throw an exception and in catch block i want to handle the exception and insert with new Terminal id value but still it is throwing 
exception,Is there any other way to solve it? Except running 2 query to select terminal Id and  match then update..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: *Except running 2 query to select terminal Id and match then update* Why not? Control the program flow by exceptions is not a good idea. BTW, is it possible to use an autoincrement or a sequence here?

Comment: You wouldn't need to set `pojo.setXxx()` again in your catch block. Maybe you could get the current TerminalID value and increment it by 1 and then insert in your catch. Also, in your catch block how would you know which TerminalID isn't already present in your DB?

Comment: Also do not catch the baseclass "exception". Only catch checked exceptions which are thrown

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for an exception, I'd do insert-ignore, check the returned row count, and if it is 0 then you can change the terminal ID.

You don't need to rebuild the whole POJO, just update the terminal ID and re-run the insert.